# Django rest framework add dict to serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, response, django-serializer

This is my serializers.py:

```
class SysUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    login_id = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SysUser
        fields = ('pk','login_id','name')
```

This is my views.py:

```
class GetUserDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        sysuser = SysUser.objects.get(id=1)
        serializer = SysUserSerializer(sysuser)
        serializer.data['gender'] = 'male' # i don't think this line is working
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

But i get this response:

```
{"pk": 1, "login_id": "john77", "name": "John"}
```

I want the response like this:

```
{"pk": 1, "login_id": "john77", "name": "John", "gender": "male"}
```

How it can be done? is it possible to do so?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye it print this {"pk": 1, "login_id": "john77", "name": "John"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem here that `serializer.data` is not instance argument, but [`property`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L225) which returns it. So you can fix this by assigning `serializer.data` to variable.

```
class GetUserDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        sysuser = SysUser.objects.get(id=1)
        serializer = SysUserSerializer(sysuser)
        data = serializer.data
        data['gender'] = 'male'
        return Response(data, status=200)
```

Also you can assign data to `serializer.data` in [`validate`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) method of serializer