# Add new values at Django rest framework pagination

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

I want to add 'isSuccess' at the pagination returns.

For example,

```
{
    "count": 1234,
    "next": "http://mydomain/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "isSuccess" : 'Success'  # <---- this one
    "results": [
        {
          'id':123,
           'name':'abc'
        }, 
        {
          'id':234,
          'name':'efg'
        },
         ...
    ]
}
```

I found [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940524/django-rest-framework-add-dict-to-serializer) but It didn't work. **How can I add new values at Django pagination return?**

this is my try:

```
class Testing(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Problem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = userSerializer
    pagination_class = userPagination

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        page = self.request.query_params.get('page')

        if page is not None:
            paginate_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(paginate_queryset, many=True)

            tmp = serializer.data
            tmp['isSuccess'] = 'Success'

            return self.get_paginated_response(tmp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try, instead of adding `isSuccess` to the serializer.data, add it to `get_paginated_response().data`

```
def get(self, request):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    page = self.request.query_params.get('page')

    if page is not None:
        paginate_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(paginate_queryset, many=True)

        tmp = serializer.data
        # tmp['isSuccess'] = 'Success'

        response = self.get_paginated_response(tmp)
        response.data['isSuccess'] = "Success"

        return Response(data=response.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    return Response(data="No Page parameter found", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The response will be something like

```
{
    "count": 1234,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
          'id':123,
           'name':'abc'
        },
        ...
    ],
    "isSuccess" : 'Success'
}
```

Comment: Also, "results" can be moved to the end of JSON with `data.move_to_end('results')`. Might be helpful for manual api browsing if results contain a long list

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding the `get_paginated_response` method in the [PageNumberPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles)

Example:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from collections import OrderedDict


class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', data),

            ('isSuccess', "Success")  # extra
        ]))
```